# Airflow : Bash Operator is not giving the results

Tags: airflow

Through Airflow , We are trying to execute below code, this script is executed with 0 return code but no result.

Referred : 
https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html

Taken same Example Pipeline definition

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)
```

Log is showing 0 return code ,But Output is empty

```
root@masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:/usr/airflow> airflow test tutorial print_date 2015-06-01
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,318] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,401] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,552] {bash_operator.py:70} INFO - Tmp dir root location:
 /tmp
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,552] {bash_operator.py:80} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpFWK0XJ//tmp/airflowtmpFWK0XJ/print_dateYEnzSO
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,552] {bash_operator.py:88} INFO - Running command: date
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,557] {bash_operator.py:97} INFO - Output:
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,561] {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - Thu Aug 22 14:22:10 EDT 2019
[2019-08-22 14:22:10,561] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
```

Comment: I don't understand: i see that `Thu Aug 22 14:22:10 EDT 2019` thing in your output; do you expect anything else?

Comment: You are right . But this also ,t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='ls',
    dag=dag) this also giving same result

Comment: are you sure you didn't forget to update `task_id` across tasks?